# Array to string conversion in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2.2.2

[image]

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   /home/pacifi48/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
>   on line 2999 Magento 2 Version 2.2.2

How to solve???

Comment: Have you find any solution regarding this issues ?

Answer (score 3):

To solve please do modification in below paths

**Path** : vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

**Under** --> public function prepareColumnValue(array $column, $value)

**Replace old code:**

```
 case 'longtext':
    $value  = (string)$value;
    if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
        $value = null;
    }
    break;
```

**With new code:**

```
case 'longtext':
    if(!is_array($value)) $value  = (string)$value;
    else $value = '';
    if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
        $value = null;
    }
    break;
```

**same error came to me now it solved**

Comment: Does your answer work or this https://snipboard.io/d9gYuj.jpg?

Comment: You should not change core code, this will be replaced in future updates. There is an underlying issue here as to why you are not getting a string.

Comment: You should under not circumstances change core code as this will break your site sooner or later and you will have no idea what you did and where.

Answer (score 0):

You have to treat the data as an array instead of an object. For example, you want to access the title of an article. If you treat the article as an object you will use getter like $article->getTitle. So, in this case, you have to access it by this way $article['title']