# magento 2 trace payment page issue array to string conversion

Tags: magento2, place-order

I am getting issue on check out page when place order button.It display

"An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again."

whaen checking log file then error is displaying

> main.CRITICAL: Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   /var/www/html/v1/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on
>   line 2999 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Array to
>   string conversion in
>   /var/www/html/v1/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on
>   line 2999 at
>   /var/www/html/v1/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}

I am not able to to trace the issue.Please let me know how to trace the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have Resolved With below changing:

**File Path** : vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

**Under** --> public function prepareColumnValue(array $column, $value)

**Replacing old code:**

```
 case 'longtext':
    $value  = (string)$value;
    if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
        $value = null;
    }
    break;
```

**by replacing below code**

```
case 'longtext':
    if(!is_array($value)) 
      $value  = (string)$value;
    else $value = '';
    if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
        $value = null;
    }
    break;
```

This is resolving my problem but now I am not sure changing this code is ok or Will t create a problem in future or any security issue?
Please give me idea?

Original Post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/224706/24878